# What do I need and how much it costs to register a car in Belgium?

Tags: car, vehicle-registration, belgium

I would be interested to know where I could find out how much would it cost to register my car in Belgium. Is going to be the first registration in Belgium for a less than 4 years old car, euro 6, Diesel, 81Kw (110PS).
Thank you!